# Java LocalDateTime giving different output on different servers. Same timezone configurations

Tags: java, linux, datetime

I Have a simple program that just outputs the time but I am getting different results on different Linux Distros.  I verified that the default timezone is set property and on SuSe I get my default timezone but on Ubuntu I get UTC time.  I can't figure out why.

Here is the code

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime nowTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.print(nowTime);
    }
}
```

On my Suse (& Windows) server this is my output

```
/home/user/test # timedatectl
      Local time: Sat 2020-04-11 12:18:49 PDT
  Universal time: Sat 2020-04-11 19:18:49 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2020-04-11 19:18:49
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
/home/user/test # java Main
2020-04-11T12:18:51.461
```

Then on my Ubuntu Distro

```
/home/user/test# timedatectl
                      Local time: Sat 2020-04-11 12:19:53 PDT
                  Universal time: Sat 2020-04-11 19:19:53 UTC
                        RTC time: Sat 2020-04-11 19:19:53
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
/home/user/test# java Main
2020-04-11T19:19:57.232828
```

What do I have to do to make sure the output is consistent no matter what OS I deploy this code on?

Edit: 
Upon adding another line of code to check what Timezone java is using this is what I got

`System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());`

Suse => Pacific Standard Time

Ubuntu => Coordinated Universal Time

So now I need to figure out why it's using a different timezone

Comment: At a guess, Java is detecting the wrong timezone in the Ubuntu machine or it's being overridden by a system/user property.  You can check what timezone Java uses by default using `System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());`

Comment: @Powerlord Yes your right.  Ubuntu output was `Coordinated Universal Time` and Suse was `Pacific Standard Time`.  Any ideas on where I can look to see where this override is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Something must of been wrong with the timezone setup on the Ubuntu server.  I re-ran the timezone configuration tool and everything works fine now

`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: In this case I can’t see your question being helpful for other readers. Please allow that I suggest that you delete it.

Comment: @OleV.V.  So you don't think it would be helpful for others with the same issue to know that it's potentially a server issue and not a app/code issue?  If I had seen someone with this same issue and saw this was a possible solution then it would of saved me a few hours of headache.

Comment: Thank you for returning on the question of deletion. Opinions differ. I am completely fine with that. Please do as you find best. After my vote your question has been closed, and don’t know whether this means that it will be deleted by a moderator at some point or not. I am not doing anything more about it.